# Error in django-nonrel settings TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am getting this error in settings of django-testapp when I run

```
pradeep@pradeep:~/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp$ python manage.py runserver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/djangoappengine/management/commands/runserver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db import connections
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/dbindexer/base.py", line 54, in DatabaseWrapper
    return Wrapper(merged_settings, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/dbindexer/base.py", line 37, in __init__
    super(BaseDatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pradeep/projects/python/gae_django_nonrel_app/django-testapp/djangoappengine/db/base.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.ops = DatabaseOperations(self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dragonx said the error was because I was using latest branch of django-nonrel and which didn't support completely django1.5 and so on. I didn't try to resolve it either because we have better options with better support and functionalitites to deploy app on PAAS such as HEROKU. So I moved on to HEROKU.

Answer (score 0):

Usually errors like this come from mismatching versions of django, djangoappengine or django-toolbox.  You'd want to double check to make sure you have the right version of each.